# How can I listen for events in the Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational log?

Tags: c#, logging, event-handling

I am trying to listen for events in the **Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational** log. I can listen to the main Windows logs, such as the application log using this code:

```
public static void SubscribeToLogEvents(string logName, EntryWrittenEventHandler customEventHandler)
{
    EventLog log = new EventLog();
    log.Log = logName;
    //when an entry is written to an event log on the local computer, customEventHandler is fired 
    log.EntryWritten += customEventHandler;
    //Set a value indicating EventLog receives 
    //System.Diagnostics.EventLog.EntryWritten event notifications. 
    log.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
} 

static void EventLogEntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs currentEvent)
{
    var log = (EventLog)sender;
    Console.WriteLine("Event Raised: |Log:{0}|Source:{1}|EventID:{2}|", log.LogDisplayName, currentEvent.Entry.Source, currentEvent.Entry.EventID);

}
```

If I use the following I can see events occurring in the Application log in real time:

```
SubscribeToLogEvents("Application", OnEntryWritten);
```

However, the events I want are in here:

[image]

How can I listen to this log? If I try this:

```
SubscribeToLogEvents("Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational", OnEntryWritten);
```

I get an error saying "Log Not Found".

Answer (score 5):

Very late, but this was the first post I found on my quest to the answer. So for people finding this at first:

```
private void AttachWatcher() {
    EventLogQuery logQuery = new EventLogQuery("Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational", PathType.LogName, "*[System[(EventID = 10000)]]");
    EventLogWatcher logWatcher = new EventLogWatcher(logQuery);
    logWatcher.EventRecordWritten += new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(EventWritten);
    logWatcher.Enabled = true;
}

private void EventWritten(Object obj, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs arg) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample! This should be added to MSDN as well!